# Surjective maps between algebraic groups induce surjective maps between connected components

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, transcendence-theory, transcendental-functions

I am reading the paper of F. Beukers, A refined version of the Siegel-Shidlovskii theorem (here is the [link](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ebeuke106/siegelshidlovskii.pdf)). The author mentions the following result in Algebraic group theory without proof.

> Lemma 2.4. Let $G_1,...,G_n$ be linear algebraic groups and $H\subset G_1\times...\times G_n$ be an algebraic subgroup such that all the
> natural projections $\pi_i:H\to G_i$ are surjective. Then the induced projections between their connected components $\pi_i:H^o\to G_i^o$ are all surjective.

I don't know how to prove this. The lemma follows if the following question is affirmative.

> Question. Let $f:H\to G$ be a surjective morphism between algebraic groups. Is it true that the induced map between connected components $f:H^o\to G^o$ is also surjective?

It is known that this is true under certain conditions (e.g., $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ is connected). However, I don't think it is true in general. I have a counter-example for (abstract) topological groups (take $\mathrm{id}:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ the identity map between the (discrete) group $\mathbb R$ and the (euclidean) group $\mathbb R$). Still, I cannot find a counter-example for algebraic groups (because of the finiteness of $H/H^o$).

So do you know any proof/reference or idea of how to prove the lemma and the question above?

Comment: It is true. With some devissage you can assume that $H$ and $G$ are both smooth. Then, the point is this $f(H^\circ)\subseteq G^\circ$ is actually closed. So, as $G^\circ$ is irreducible (a general fact about algebraic groups), it suffices to show that the dimension of $f(H^\circ)$ and $G^\circ$ are the same. But, for this it suffices to show that $\dim(H^\circ)-\dim(\ker(f^\circ))=\dim(G^\circ)$ But, this is equivalent to $\dim(H)-\dim(\ker(f))=\dim(G)$ which follows from surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you very much! With your proof, we also have $f(H^o)=f(H)^o$ for any (not necessarily surjective) morphism $f$.

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $\times$ using `\cdots`.